# Issues aligning checkboxes and text inputs in jQuery Mobile

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I can't this to work. It may be simple, but I just can't get the checkboxes to align horizontally with its respective text inputs side by side.

This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emfuentes27/sczxmquj/)

HTML

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
<div data-role="fieldcontain" style="float:left; width:100%">
    <input type="checkbox" name="1" id="1" value="1" />
    <input type="text" name="name" id="basic1" value="A" />
</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain" style="float: left; width:100%">
    <input type="checkbox" name="2" id="2" value="2" />
    <input type="text" name="name" id="basic2" value="B" />
</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain" style="float: left; width:100%">
    <input type="checkbox" name="3" id="3" value="3" />
    <input type="text" name="name" id="basic3" value="C" />
</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain" style="float: left; width:100%">
    <input type="checkbox" name="3" id="4" value="4" />
    <input type="text" name="name" id="basic4" value="D" />
</div>
</fieldset>
```

I also tried using grids:

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
<div class="ui-block-a">
    <input type="checkbox" name="jobtype" id="1a" value="1" />
</div>
<div class="ui-block-b">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="basic1a" value="A" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.ui-input-text {
width: 80%;
float:right;
display:inline
}
.ui-block-a {
width:20%
}
.ui-block-b {
width:80%;
}
```

What am I missing here? Thanks!

Comment: Here is one way: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/sczxmquj/6/

Comment: @ezanker, this works great, why don't you write it as an answer, so I can accept it for you? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have jQM enhance the checkbox, surround the input element with a label:

```
<div>
    <div data-role="controlgroup" style="float:left; width:100%">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="jobtype" id="1" value="1" /></label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="basic1" value="A" />
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain" style="float: left; width:100%">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="jobtype" id="2" value="2" /></label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="basic2" value="B" />
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain" style="float: left; width:100%">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="jobtype" id="3" value="3" /></label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="basic3" value="C" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Then to line things up and equalize the heights:

```
.ui-checkbox {
    width: 19%;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    margin-top: 8px !important;  
}
.ui-checkbox label {    
  height: 12.2px;  
}
.ui-input-text {
    width: 80%;
    float:right;
    display:inline
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/sczxmquj/8/)**

You could also do this with a listview:

```
    <div class="container">
        <ul data-role="listview" class="has-checkDiv">
            <li>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="name1" id="basic1" value="A" />
                </div>
                <div class="checkDiv">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="jobtype" id="1a" value="1" />
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="name2" id="basic2" value="B" />
                </div>
                <div class="checkDiv">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="jobtype" id="1b" value="1" />
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

.container {
    padding-top: 12px;
}

.has-checkDiv > li > div:first-child {
    margin-left: 40px !important;
}
.checkDiv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 40px;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 100;
}
.checkDiv .ui-checkbox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 20px;
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: -11px;
    margin-left: -11px;
}
```

> [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/sczxmquj/7/)